# Striping trail whitespaces in json

Tags: python, json, strip

I have a big json file with more than 1000 entries. This json gets fed into downstream library for further processing. I'm trying to look for a simpler way to get rid of all trailing whitespaces in the value part.

```
{
    "Country": [
        {
            "country_name": "Germany ",
            "country_capital": " Berlin",
            "concept_description": "Germany is also known as Deutschland ",
            "country_cities": [
                "Frankfurt"
            ],
            "neighbouring_countries": [
                " Belgium",
                "France "
            ],
            "country_group": "Europe "
        },
            {
            "country_name": " France ",
            "country_capital": " Paris",
            "concept_description": "Effiel Tower is in paris ",
            "country_cities": [
                " montpellier"
            ],
            "neighbouring_countries": [
                " Belgium",
                "Spain "
            ],
            "country_group": "Europe "
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use `String.strip()` and list comprehension to achieve this `mylist = [[x.strip() for x in y] for y in mylist]`. But, certain keys have values as list and some are just string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a recursive function to strip everything?

```
def strip(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.strip()
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return list(map(strip, value))
    # handle dict etc, by recursive call to `strip()`
```

If the structure is consistent, for eg. `neighbouring_countries` is always a list, you can use any of the data validation libraries. I prefer [`schema` myself](https://pypi.org/project/schema/).